# Writing to statically-sized file with offset

Tags: rust

I am trying to write bytes to a file with random access in the context of downloading random chunks of the file and assembling them in-place. The `std::io::Write` seem to be limited to sequential writing so I am currently using the following implementation which first needs to download all the chunks and then do big [`write_all`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#method.write_all) once all the chunks are in memory.

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;
use rand; // 0.7.3

fn download<W: std::io::Write>(writer: &mut W) -> std::io::Result<()>
{
    // the size (20) is known
    let mut buf = [0u8; 20];
    
    // simulate downloading four 5 byte chunks at random disjoint slices in *buf*
    for n in (0..20).step_by(5).collect::<Vec<usize>>().choose_multiple(&mut thread_rng(), 4) {
        let n = *n as usize;
        let chunk: [u8; 5] = rand::random();
        buf[n..n+5].clone_from_slice(&chunk);
    }
    
    println!("filled buffer: {:?}", buf);
    
    // finally, do (unbuffered) write
    writer.write_all(&buf)?;
    
    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let mut f = std::fs::File::create("foo.txt")?;
    download(&mut f)?;
    
    Ok(())
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7d1f2c972ce49400929ad7953b6b5e23)

With large files I think this solution may consume to much memory and I would rather write each `chunk` directly into the file without any intermediate buffer. I see there is [`write_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.FileExt.html#tymethod.write_at) in the documentation, but is this method unique for unix systems? I am looking for a generic solution.

Intuitively, I would want something like this to work:

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;
use rand; // 0.7.3

fn download<W: std::io::Write>(writer: &mut W) -> std::io::Result<()>
{
    // the size (20) is known
    writer.reserve(20)?;

    // simulate downloading four 5 byte chunks at random disjoint slices in *buf*
    for n in (0..20).step_by(5).collect::<Vec<usize>>().choose_multiple(&mut thread_rng(), 4) {
        let n = *n as usize;
        let chunk: [u8; 5] = rand::random();
        writer.write_at(chunk, n)?;
    }

    Ok(())
}

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {

    let mut f = std::fs::File::create("foo.txt")?;
    download(&mut f)?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Is there any specialization for writing to random access file output? Can I use a memory mapped file? Doing a quick search I could only find the [positioned-io](https://github.com/vasi/positioned-io) crate, which has not been updated in 3 years. Is there anything similar to this crate in the rust standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [`Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html).  `File` implements both `Seek` and `Write` so you just need to bound on `Seek` as well:

```
use std::io::{Write, Seek, SeekFrom, Result as IoResult};

fn download<W: Write + Seek>(writer: &mut W) -> IoResult<()> { /* ... */ }
```

Now you can do `writer.seek(SeekFrom::Start(*n as u64 * CHUNK_SIZE))?;` before writing out the chunk.